# CSS: position of a image in a header

Tags: html, css

i am trying to position a logo in the middle of a the header, and push it to the buttom.
I got a problem with firefox size (px , em, %) sizes when the image is in the buttom of the header in chrome and IE9, in fire fox it getting out of the border (overflow?).

is there a way to position the image or any object for that matter in the buttom of div in all the browsers?

here my code, mybee it will give you idea what im doing worng:

css:

```
#header
{
   background-image:url("../images/roundShapBrickWall.jpg");

   background-repeat:repeat-x;

    position:relative;
    width:inherit;
    height:14.1em;


}
#header img
{
    position:relative;    // <--- somewhere here i think is the problem.
    width:50%;
    top:17%; 
}
```

info: this is the position i want it to have, it sits in the middle and the buttom of the header, but in firefox in getting out of the border of the header.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried: "position:absolute;bottom:0;" to your "#header img"?

Comment: yeah that did the trick! and i learned somthing new thank you!

Comment: That's great! Feel free to mark it as your answer if this question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using `position:relative` and `position:absolute` by setting in `#header` section `text-align: center` and adjust image position with margin. Also vertical position can be set with margin. But this would only work if you don't have other content in header.